# How to make a function that return coordinates from address swift 4

Tags: swift, function, clgeocoder

Hi I want to receive the coordinates of an address. I made this function but not works. Return alway 0.0, 0.0

```
 func getCoordinates(address: String)->(Double, Double){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
            guard let placemarks = placemarks, let location = placemarks.first?.location else {  return }
            latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
            longitude = location.coordinate.longitude

        }
    }
    return (latitude ?? 0.0, longitude ?? 0.0)

}
```

Comment: please make more search about sync / async process in Swift. the `return` line always executed before `DispatchQueue.main.async` block this is why you always fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a completion and insert the main queue block inside the callback of the geocoder

```
func getCoordinates(_ address: String,completion:@escaping((CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> ())){
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
        guard let placemarks = placemarks, let location = placemarks.first?.location else {  return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(location.coordinate)
        }
    }
}
```

call

```
getCoordinates("someAdd") {  loc in

}
```

Comment: Thanks the best!